# How to programmatically find the inverse of a 2x2 matrix (mod 26).

Tags: matrices, modules, cryptography

I'm trying to create a hill cipher utility. One feature I want is to be able to compute the key if you have the plaintext and ciphertext.

$C$ = ciphertext matrix ($2\times 2$), $P$ = plaintext matrix $\left(2\times\frac{N}{2}\right)$, $K$ = key ($2\times 2$).

$$PK = C$$

So if I have $C$ and $P$, then $K = P^{-1}C$. How do I best find $P^{-1}$?

EDIT: It is important to note that this is all mod $26$. Sorry.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960190) related question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the direct formula for $2 \times 2$:

$$ \pmatrix{a & b\\
c & d}^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{d & -b\\-c & a}$$

Comment: The problem is that doesn't work out in with the modular.

I don't know how to format this nicely, sorry.

but lets say our plaintext is b,a,z,z.

{{b,a},
{z,z}} = 
{{1,0},
{25,25}}

then if we try multiplying by 1/(ad-ab) we get a fraction. That doesn't work when you are working with only discrete values.

Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be the modular inverse, the extended gcd algorithm would be one way to do it. In your example, 25 is its own inverse, another example is $3^{-1} \equiv 9 (mod 26)$ since $3 \times 9 = 27 \equiv 1 (mod 26)$

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. So {{1,0},{25,25}}^(-1) actually works out to {{1,0},{25,25}}, right?

Comment: Yes! Also, consider that $2$ and $13$ and any multiples (basically just even numbers and the number $13$) do not have modular inverses.